# React JS Play sound continuously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a little app in react js that will play and pause music/sounds. When the song finishes I want the track to start again from the beginning. At the moment, the first time the song ends it will start again but once that finishes it doesn't play again.

I also have a stop button, that stops the track the first time it's pressed, but then it won't work again. Is anyone able to help? I am sure I am just doing something silly

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Controls(props) {
  const audio = new Audio(props.source);
  const [isPlaying, playStatus] = useState(false);
  let interval;

  function playState() {
    console.log(isPlaying);
    console.log("here: Playing");
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    playStatus(true);
    startTimer(props.duration);
  }

  function pauseState() {
    console.log(isPlaying);
    console.log("here 1");
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.pause();
    clearInterval(interval);
    playStatus(false);
  }

  function startTimer(seconds) {
    let currentPlayTime = 0;
    if (currentPlayTime === 0) {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        currentPlayTime++;
        if (currentPlayTime === seconds) {
          playState();
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      alert("Running");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button className="Button" onClick={playState}>
        Play
      </button>
      <button className="Button" onClick={pauseState}>
        Stop
      </button>
      <audio id="myAudio" src={props.source} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Controls;
```

Link to code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/soundsappppppp-oe4gf?file=/src/components/Controls.jsx:0-1172

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this link. It's a react-player npm package, that you can upload your own files or use from URLs. You can specify loop, so it automatically loops again when it ends https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I've figured it out. Thanks so Much @Dani I've been messing about for ages trying to get this work!

Comment: @Jjjay2020 You are meant to tell us how you solved by answering your own question below and marking it as done. At least that's the best practice on the platform if you expect other people to help you.